# CakePHP load default controller

Tags: cakephp

I want to write a controller, a model and a view for a website. I writed it, and added it to the routes.php, but it loads the root path (contents controller). It's not display any errors, just redirecting to the root. I use the 1.1.16.5421 version of the CakePHP.

This is my routes.php:

```
$Route->connect('/', array('controller' => 'contents'));
$Route->connect('/services', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'services'));
$Route->connect('/kapcsolat', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'contact_us'));
$Route->connect('/rolunk', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'about'));
$Route->connect('/privacy-notes', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'show', 1));
$Route->connect('/conditions-of-use', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'show', 2));
$Route->connect('/vasarlasi_folyamat', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'show', 3));


$Route->connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
$Route->connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
$Route->connect('/register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register'));
$Route->connect('/my_account', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'my_account'));

$Route->connect('/products/special', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'show_special'));
$Route->connect('/products/new', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'show_new'));

$Route->connect('/advanced_search', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'advanced_search'));

$Route->connect('/gallery', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'show', 14));

$Route->connect('/gallery', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'show', 14));
$Route->connect('/ajandek', array('controller' => 'ajandek', 'action' => 'toXML'));
```

This is my controller:

```
class AjandekController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'ajandek';
    var $helpers = array('Html');
    var $uses = array('ajandek');
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
    public function toXML($id=null){
        if ($id){
            $this->loadModel('AjandekModel');
            $this->set('ajandek', $this->AjandekModel->byID($id));
        }
    }
}
```

The model:

```
class AjandekModel extends AppModel{
    var $name="products";
    public function byID($id=null){
        if ($id){
            return $this->findAll(array(
                'id'=>$id
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<products>
    <?php
        foreach ($content as $item){
            ?>
                <product>
                        <product_id><?php echo $item['ajandek']['id']; ?></product_id>
                        <name><![CDATA[]]></name>
                        <redirect_url><![CDATA[]]></redirect_url>
                        <image_url><?php echo $item['ajandek']['image']; ?></image_url>
                        <image_url_2></image_url_2>
                        <image_url_3></image_url_3>
                        <price><?php echo $item['ajandek']['price']; ?></price>
                        <old_price></old_price>
                        <discount_percent></discount_percent>
                        <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
                <category_id></category_id>
                <product_tags>
                        <ferfi></ferfi>
                        <no></no>
                        <gyerek></gyerek>
                        <felnott></felnott>
                        <idos></idos>
                        </product_tags>
                </product>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</products>
```

I hope how somebody can help me solve it. :(

Comment: Would be good if you'd show the routes that hide behind the `...`. Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: I added the missing informations to the question. :)

Comment: CakePHP 1.1? Really? That's waaaaaaay too old for me, sorry, don't know about its ins and outs. However, in case the other routes do work fine and do not interfere your added route, it might be something in your `AppController::beforeFilter()` (assuming it actually reaches your `Ajandek` controller), or maybe the casing in `AjandekController::$name/$uses` (I would expect that the string must start with an uppercase letter). I'd suggest to do some debugging by for example adding output here and there to check where exactly it bails out on its way to your controller action.